# Emacs Org-mode insert multiple images

Tags: image, emacs, elisp, org-mode

When I use org-mode in emacs, I usually do `[[./figure1.png]]` to insert a figure. But now I have about 200 figures and I need to visually check them all. I might be able to do this by using multiple cursors but I am wondering if there's any better way to do this. I am hoping like `[[./figure*.png]]` to insert all figures. Thanks,

Comment: drag-and-drop with https://github.com/abo-abo/org-download

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use babel with raw output:

```
#+name: including-them-all
#+begin_src sh :results raw
  for i in figure*.png; do
      echo "[[file:$i]]"
  done
#+end_src
```

a `C-cC-c` on this will run the small shell script, and use its result as it was wrotten in org, and as such it will include you images.

Comment: I forgot to mention I was using `python` to plot all these png files. So I did the similar approach with `print '[['+filename+']]' `.